# Criar variável no iReport para o banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, ireport

Necessito criar um relatório do mês selecionado com as informações contidas no banco, para isso pretendo criar uma variável no iReport que receba o mês (pelo netbens) a qual será comparado com o sql existente no Ireport que estar conectado diretamente com o banco.

Metrodo iReport:

```
public void imprimir() {
    try {

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:\\Users\\costa\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Relatorio\\Estoque.jasper", null, conexao);

        JasperViewer.viewReport(print, false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

SQL presente no iReport:

```
select * from Hospede h where DATE_FORMAT(h.horaini,'%m') = variavel
```

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Qual sua dúvida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso você terá que criar um parâmetro. No iReport faça o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele vai criar um novo parâmetro com nome "parameter1", você precisará ir em propriedades e editar o nome e o tipo dele.

Para usá-lo na sua query a notação será a seguinte $P{nomeparametro}

```
select * from Hospede h where DATE_FORMAT(h.horaini,'%m') = $P{nomeparametro}
```

No código java:

```
HashMap params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("nomeparametro", parametro);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:\\Users\\costa\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Relatorio\\Estoque.jasper", params, conexao);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, caso saiba algum tutorial sobre o iReport para me indicar seria de grande ajuda